# HTML tags question

Tags: php, html

Something basic that i don't understand:

I have `header.php` with navigation bar for my site. Inside it, there's a `<head>...</head>` section.

Now, in each other page of my site, I'm using `require_once 'header.php'` so that each page will show the navigation bar. **But**, I need also specific `<head>...</head>` sections to the different page.

For example, in page `customers.php`, I'm using `<script>...</script>` to include the jQuery library. I don't need to include it in other pages.

Now, searching the web I see that *multiple head tags is wrong syntax*.

So, how  can anyone:

1. avoid multiple "head" tags
   WHILE
2. separating his work to different PHP files and including them  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid multiple tags"?

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm sorry, I've re-edited the question (wasn't aware of StackOverflow's rules for formatting). i'd appreciate if you can read it again now and it will be clearer :)

Comment: there's a bright `?` button at the top of the editor on this site. Click it next time, it has plenty of information on formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your page structure and employ templates.
Instead of loading header at the top of the code, you have to do it at the bottom!
And page code should output not a word, but collect all data in variables. 
And only after that output can be started by calling template.

A example layout is going to be like this:

First. page itself.
it outputs **nothing** but only gather required data and calls a template:

```
<?
//include our settings, connect to database etc.
include dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/cfg/settings.php';
//getting required data
$DATA=dbgetarr("SELECT * FROM links");
$pagetitle = "Links to friend sites";
//etc
//and then call a template:
$tpl = "links.php";
include "template.php";
?>
```

Next, `template.php` which is your main site template, consists of your header and footer:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My site. <?=$pagetitle?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<? include $tpl ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And, finally, `links.php` is the actual page template:

```
<h2><?=$pagetitle?></h2>
<ul>
<? foreach($DATA as $row): ?>
<li><a href="<?=$row['link']?>" target="_blank"><?=$row['name']?></a></li>
<? endforeach ?>
<ul>
```

easy, clean and maintainable.

there are many advantages in such approach:

- as requested, you can populate header with actual page-relevant data.
- HTTP headers can be sent as well, before any output. It includes cookies, sessions, cache-control and many more.
- it's 2011 today. AJAX era. You may wish change your code to return JSONed data instead of whole HTML page. It's going to be easy using such layout.
- Imagine you're going to create very similar site with just different design. You will have to change only templates and don't touch engine files. That's really great advantage of using templates.

Comment: Thanks Col! I think that i understand the concept. indeed it looks to me like the best practice.

Comment: @adler thanks. I've added some other benefits to get from this layout. and there are numerous others

Comment: Col., so in this fashion would you also set something like $head_scripts = "<script>...</script><script>...</script>..." in the page itself, and then echo it in the template between <head>...</head>?

Comment: @adler it depends. May be you should choose Andre's answer for this question, as he had listed all possible variants.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some simple ways you can look at.

- You can have jQuery on the pages
  that don't need it; once it's
  downloaded it will be cached so it
  still wont use more bandwidth.
- You can move out the closing `</head>`
  tag from header.php and close the
  `<head>` tag in the page that's including
  header.php.
- You can include javascript anywhere
  on a page, not only in the header.

You can also do something like this.
Before you do `require_once 'header.php';` you put a variable called `$jquery = true;`

In your header.php file you check if `$jquery` is set to true, if it is, you include jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Andre, 1. i will check on js caching 2. moving /head from header will disable me from putting body contents in the header. 3. is it legitimate practice to put a general js function out of the head?? 4. nice idea (using the variables). thanks again

Answer (score 0):

in header.php 
you can type like this

```
<head>    
<?php echo $script; ?>
</head>
```

then in your customers.php
you can first assign the variable

```
$script = '<script>...</script>'
```

then

```
require_once 'header.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution.

1. You create a global variable before including `header.php`.
2. You test this variable in `header.php`.
3. If it is true, You print script or something. Something like this:

   ```
   <!-- Fragment of header.php -->
   <?php if ($i_want_jquery): ?>
   <script ...>
   ...
   </script>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

On the other hand, a template may be a better solution.